# how to represent non-binary trees with 1D-arrays?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, tree

A way to use 1D-arrays to represent non-binary trees

we can use 1D-array for representing binary trees when we have a finite and small number of nodes
whereas a node at index i has two sons at indices 2*i and 2*i+1.
can I use 1D-arrays for storing non-binary trees, (when a node has more than 2 sons), in the same manner?
I thought of using this way to store a tree with 3 sons at most where the index of the node is i and its sons are at 3*i, 3*i + 1 and 3*i + 2.. but doing so, i am left with a lot of empty (not used) array cells.
is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not convinced of your premise. A binary tree represented as you describe will *also* typically have lots of empty array cells, unless it's a complete binary tree -- but then, a complete ternary tree wouldn't have lots of empty array cells, either.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution to pack all nodes in a one-dimensional array.

Each node consist of a variable-number of array cells. The first cell of the node is the count C of its child nodes. The next C cells contain the indexes of the first cell of its child nodes in the array.

For example:

```
Indexes: 0 1 2 3 4
Values:  2 3 4 0 0
```

is a graph with of 3 nodes; 1 node that has 2 child nodes. First node is at cell index 0 whose value is 2, the number of its child nodes. Next 2 values are the indexes of the child nodes, 3 and 4. Cells at indexes 3 and 4 have values 0 because they have no child node.

Comment: @Muaz Kassm  Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: A trick you can use if you can choose the IDs of nodes is to partition nodes with no children and nodes with no siblings - then you can avoid any wasted space. The "indexes" array holds non-leaf nodes and the "values" array holds only nodes with siblings.